# What are the most common uses of piri piri sauce (other than with chicken)?

Tags: bread, hot-sauce

I have experimenting in the kitchen. I decided to use some extra hot piri piri sauce with some bacon on a Stottie cake. It tasted magical and I am tempted to repeat the process sometime soon. What else goes with piri piri, other than chicken? What are the most common uses of piri piri sauce?

Comment: This is very general and out of the scope of the [`Culinary-Uses` tag](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culinary-uses); try referring to the higher voted questions from there and see if you can tighten up this question

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the question. It was answered exactly how it was intended to be. Try spending your time more productively by observing such simple facts.

Comment: the reason you to tighten it up goes as follows by way of parallel; Q: "What are some other uses of [a bechamel]?" reasons to close (1) too general, trivial - google it yourself, (2) recipe request, list of x, too broad - no objective way of analyzing  any given answer for acceptance. By "tighten it up", I just meant ask in such a way as to address those two concerns; show that (1) you have googled it but ran into some [limitation with results] and/or (2) give criteria for selecting a "right" answer worth accepting. In (2) I would ask, what made you select "[use it with mussels]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a friend that made Mussels using the piri piri sauce.  I also think that it might be tasty if you use that sauce on a nice burger!